# C# refine method code for query

Tags: c#

i am trying to create a method to access an access2010 .accdb database simply by calling the method with the SQL statement. this method currently works after my many hours of "trial and error". Are there any ways to refine this piece of code to make it more robust yet simpler because of the many steps involved. (new connection, then new command, then new reader etc seems to be too many of a steps in just executing one SQL command?)

btw this code is to query a database and return a string.

```
public static string getString(string SQL)
{   
    using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = SQL;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        connection.Open();

        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                return reader.GetString(0).ToString();
            }
        }

        return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks pretty short to me. how short do you want it? You could open your connection elsewhere just once, but I would keep opening it each time if I were you (unless you are doing a lot of queries in one go)... in short, leave it as it is ... oh, and you look like you are not using command parameters to prevent from SQL injection - search on Google if you need to

Comment: My suggestion would be to remove the inner using, you only need one using, and instead of execute reader use execute scalar becouse you are returning only one record

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you will at most read one value, you could use the [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) method:

```
using(var connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
using(var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = SQL;
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    connection.Open();

    var value = command.ExecuteScalar();

    return value == DBNull.Value ? null : value.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion this method looks very good, there is no much to add if not exception logging with a log of the SQL statement on a logging system.

mind also that you are actually returning a scalar string only, for that you could use the `ExecuteScalar` and avoid the reader completely.